# javascript function not defines error in Symfony3 twig file

Tags: javascript, html, twig, assets, symfony

I'm using Symfony3 for my project and I'm facing *ReferenceError: optionOneChange is not defined* error.

Here's my HTML Twig file:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    <p id="question">{{ questions[0].desc }}</p>
    <form id="form">
        <input type="radio" id="option1" onclick="optionOneChange(1)"> {{ questions[0].ans1}}<br>
        <input type="radio" id="option2" onclick="optionOneChange(2)"> {{ questions[0].ans2}}<br>
        <input type="radio" id="option3" onclick="optionOneChange(3)"> {{ questions[0].ans3}}<br>
        <input type="radio" id="option4" onclick="optionOneChange(4)"> {{ questions[0].ans4}}<br>
    </form>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}

    <script src=" {{ asset('js/playGame.js') }}"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

and here's *playGame.js* file:

```
function optionOneChange(option)
{
    if (option == 1)
        $(document).getElementById("question").innerHTML = "one";
    else if (option == 2)
        $(document).getElementById("question").innerHTML = "two";
    else if (option == 3)
        $(document).getElementById("question").innerHTML = "three";
    else if (option == 4)
        $(document).getElementById("question").innerHTML = "four";
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check in the development tools if the file `playGame.js` has been loaded.

Comment: I've checked and it's loaded. I've placed the script directly in script tag without using asset and the result is as same.

Comment: Your selector `$(document)` looks weird, but that certainly doesn't trow the ReferenceError. I'd still change that to `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: It used to be documnet at first and it didn't work

Comment: Did it throw ReferenceError: optionOneChange is not defined, too?

Comment: Actually that's the error and my problem !

Comment: It's hard to say from here what's wrong. You have to go the hard way and debug it step by step in the development tools of your browser. Try to execute the function in the console, if it doesn't work proceed further, define the function in the console, then select a radio button and see what happens. Add some `console.log()` outputs to your JS, also outside the function, to see if and how far it gets executed. I'm sorry I can't help you more.

Comment: Open developer tools, paste optionOneChange in console and press enter. Is optionOneChange available?

Comment: i've done it and the result is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to put a single quote around the parameter passed into your js function like so:

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="radio" id="option1" onclick="optionOneChange('1')"> {{ questions[0].ans1}}<br>
  <input type="radio" id="option2" onclick="optionOneChange('2')"> {{ questions[0].ans2}}<br>
  <input type="radio" id="option3" onclick="optionOneChange('3')"> {{ questions[0].ans3}}<br>
  <input type="radio" id="option4" onclick="optionOneChange('4')"> {{ questions[0].ans4}}<br>
</form>
```

Also, is your posting a cut & paste from your code? If so, I see a problem here:

```
<script src=" {{ asset('js/playGame.js') }}"></script>
```

There is an extra space in front, so try this instead:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/playGame.js') }}"></script>
```

Not sure if that helps or not, but you can check.